# refresh a javascript file after an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I am using a keynav plugin that allows me to navigate up and down though a list.

This list is dynamically generated using ajax and mysql. the suggesstions appear when someone begins to search into an input box.

if the user clicks off and the list closes and then begins a new search, when the list is generated the second time, the keyboard navigation breaks. I dont want the page to refresh but is there anyway to "refresh", "reload" the keyvav.js or possibly the function iteself after the user closes the list? so the file loads and hopefully works correctly when the user tries to search again.

```
 $('body').click(function() {
    $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
     .....do magic "refresh" .....
 });
```

Comment: why does the keyboard navigation break with a new search? -- it sounds like this is where the fix should be, not in reloading the JS file.

Comment: I really dont know, its not making sense- I was looking for an alternative solution because as soon as i reload the page, its fine.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a broken script, or that it's being used incorrectly.

Comment: fixed it, there was a function that resets the key nav functionalty.added it just after the ajaxs generates the results. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is set up by the a init() function couldnt you just rerun that, but if you really want to reload the whole script you could get the file content with a ajax request then eval() it. not the best way because eval is murder on computers because it reboots the javascript encoder but it will do what you need